# PulseAudio - Return Suspension State of Sink as Boolean in Bash

Tags: debian, pulseaudio, tint2

I am using `openbox`/`tint2` executors in combination with `pactl` to make an alterntive volume monitor and was wondering if `pactl` had a way of declaring whether or not mute was activated so I could have the monitor adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pacmd` instead of `pactl` (I've honestly no idea why there are two of them). `pacmd list-sinks` will list all sinks, including a `muted: yes/no` attribute. Output will need parsing with `grep`, `awk` etc.

Comment: The output of `pacmd list-sinks` is basically the same as `pactl list sinks`. For this use case at least, I don't think there's any advantage to using one or the other.